# T-SQL use operator '&' like function SUM/COUNT/etc

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, operators

Hi, 
in SQL-Server (2014) i search too make a request like this:

```
SELECT 
  T.[Text],
  &(T.[Numeric])
FROM 
  MyTable AS T
GROUP BY 
  T.[Text];
```

I would like use '&' and '|' like SUM()/MAX()/COUNT()/MIN() functions. 
Somebody can help me ?

EDIT: 
Need too:

```
SELECT 
  T.[Text],
  |(T.[Numeric])
FROM 
  MyTable AS T
GROUP BY 
  T.[Text];
```

EDIT 2:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[1L_Tests](
  [ID_Test]   [int] NOT NULL,
  [Text]     [varchar](5) NOT NULL,
  [Numeric] [int] NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ([ID_Test])
);  
GO
INSERT INTO [dbo].[1L_Tests] 
  ([ID_Test], [Text], [Numeric])
VALUES
  (1,  'KCH', 0)
  ,(2, 'KCH', 12)
  ,(3, 'KCH', 13)
  ,(4, 'DAF', 9)
  ,(5, 'DAF', 7)
  ,(6, 'LDE', 29)
  ,(7, 'LDE', 37)
  ,(8, 'LDE', 46);
GO
SELECT 
  T.[Text],
  &(T.[Numeric]) AS 'Inter',
  |(T.[Numeric]) AS 'Union'
FROM 
  [1L_Tests] AS T
GROUP BY 
  T.[Text];
```

I Expected:

```
 Text | Inter | Union
 KCH  ;   0   ;  13
 DAF  ;   1   ;  15
 LDE  ;   4   ;  63
```

Comment: And what is `&` supposed to be doing?  Sample data and desired results really help.

Comment: whats stopping you from using them?

Comment: You may substitute either `SUM` or `MAX` for the `&` and in both cases your query should run.

Comment: Is this really T-SQL? The quote operators in SQL Server are Brackets (`[]`), not reversed apostrophes (`\``).

Comment: i have read this request for the sample, the synthax isn't good

Comment: But | & are not valid TSQL commands.  Seriously doubt you can do this in straight TSQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server doesn't have a bitwise aggregate AND.  If you know how many bits you want, you can do it bit-by-bit:

```
select . . .,
       min(t.number & 1) | min(t.number & 2) | min(t.number & 4) | . . .
from . . .
```

Bitwise operations often suggest premature optimization in a database.  It is usually better to represent the "bits" as separate flags.

Comment: @KantinCharignon . . . This answers the question that you asked.  If you have another question, you should ask it as *another* question, not by modifying an already answered question and not in the comments.

Comment: Ok, sorry. My bad